# How to change css style of input and some text in one function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic, colors

We have some data that user enters

[image]

and the result after calculation

[image]

so is it possible to change css style of the text (color and font-family) "Fe" and background-color of input at the same time?

I have tried this:

```
function convcase(word) { 
document.convert.Ca.value = BuckwheatCa * document.convert.Buckwheat.value
    if(document.convert.Fe.value < 10){
    document.getElementById("Fe_t").style.color="red";}
    else { document.getElementById("Fe_t").style.color="blue";
    };
}
```

but can't access to the Fe_b id and can't change font-family of the text

```
<td id='Fe_t'>Fe</td> <td id='Fe_b'><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Fe" DISABLED></td>
```

maybe it is possible with jquery?

Comment: What do you mean *"an't access to the input id"*? the input doesn't have an id...

Comment: yes, you right, I mean can't access to the  Fe_b id @T J

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or plunket?

Comment: unfortunately my input doesn't work on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/urc_7/k1ass57v/ @mulla.azzi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the input using jQuery like `$("#Fe_b input")`. You can set multiple css properties at once by passing an object containing the css property values to the [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function:

```
function convcase(word) { 
 document.convert.Ca.value = BuckwheatCa * document.convert.Buckwheat.value
  if(document.convert.Fe.value < 10){
   $("#Fe_t").css("color","red");
   $("#Fe_b input").css({"background":"grey","font-family":"fantasy"});
  }
  else {
   $("#Fe_t").css("color","blue");
   $("#Fe_b input").css({"background":"white","font-family":"sans-serif"});
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure Javascript, you can use [`getElementsByTabName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) to access the input element like this:

```
document.getElementById("Fe_b").getElementsByTagName('input')[0].style.color = 'red';
```

You will get an array of input elements, and use `[0]` to select the first one.